# Javascript call to pageMethod in vb.net not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, pagemethods

My code works in a new project with VS2010. I want it to work in my current VS2013 project and am not sure what is wrong.

Javascript

```
    window.onload = function () {
        var name = "simon"
        PageMethods.GetContactName(name,CallSuccess, CallFailed)   
    }


    function CallSuccess(res) {
        alert(res)
    }

    // alert message on some failure
    function CallFailed(res) {
        alert("hellofailed")
    }
```

VB

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetContactName(name) As String
    Return "hello " & name
End Function
```

The javascript call appears to be successful, although the alert(res) in my callsuccess seems to contain the full aspx page code as this is what is contained in my alert.

I have tried putting a break point on the VB method but this never gets hit. I tried to rename the "GetContactName" method to "GetContactName1" I then received a javascript error saying that it cannot find "GetContactName" which leads me to suspect that the method is getting called, but this doesn't explain why the break point is not being hit.

Answer (score 1):

In your VB
replace

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetContactName(name) As String
    Return "hello " & name
    End Function
```

by

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetContactName(name As String) As String
    Return "hello " & name
    End Function
```

Hope this should work